# How to clear content of div using ICheck.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, icheck

I want to clear the content of div after the checkboxes is unchecked. Also when the checkboxes is checked, the content should be visible.

I have tried it, but it won't clear the content after I uncheck the checkbox. It just add more content when its checked..

Here's my ajax code.

```
$('.myCheck').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getCategoryItems',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            name: $(this).attr("name")
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#displayCarsSection").append(data);
        }
    });

    } else {
        $("#displayCarsSection").html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: That code should work. Show us a jsFiddle with your problem. Or some html. Also you should just use `empty()` instead of `html('')`.

Comment: According to documentation, ifChecked is triggered only when check box is checked. Did you try ifUnchecked event?

Comment: @EricGuan I have also tried empty() with no results. I would like to show you jsFiddle, but I need some time. I will post it on jsFiddle later.

Comment: @Chitrang No, I didn't use ifUnchecked event. Could you guide me on this  please? Thanks!

Comment: Added answer.. Note that ifChecked is triggered when checkbox is checked so you don't need to check again inside event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to clear check box specific data when it is unchecked, you can store it in an object. So, whenever a check box is checked or unchecked, you can clear the div and use that object to generate new data to append to div.

```
var checkBoxData = {};    

$('.myCheck').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    var checkBoxIndex = $(this).index();
    // This callback is triggered when checkbox is checked
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getCategoryItems',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            name: $(this).attr("name")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            checkBoxData[checkBoxIndex] = data;
            updateCarsSection();  
        }
    });
});

$('.myCheck').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    // This callback is triggered when checkbox is unchecked
    checkBoxData[$(this).index()] = ""; 
    updateCarsSection();       
}

function updateCarsSection()
{
    // Clear out the div
    $("#displayCarsSection").empty();
    var updatedData = "";
    $.each(checkBoxData, function (key, value) {            
        updatedData += value;
    });
    // Append data based on currently selected checkboxes
    $("#displayCarsSection").append(updatedData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It won't add more content when its checked. That's great. But when I check the first checkbox and the second checkbox, and then uncheck one of these checkbox, it just clear all the content.

Comment: When I try to uncheck the checkbox, the content is still there. It won't be removed. And If I check another checkboxes it will not add the contents together.. Thanks.

Comment: It was my bad.. `this` refers to different object inside success handler for ajax call.. Edited the answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But when I check another checkboxes it will not add the contents together..

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work. :) I just used "ifChanged" instead of "IfChecked"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a change listener? As far as I know, 'click' should also work.

See https://jsfiddle.net/kkryao5g/1/

JavaScript

```
$('.myCheck').on('change', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#displayCarsSection").append($(this).attr('id'));
    } else {
        $("#displayCarsSection").html('');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck1"> <label for="myCheck1">Option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck2"> <label for="myCheck2">Option 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck3"> <label for="myCheck3">Option 3</label>
<br><br>
<span id="displayCarsSection"></span>
```

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know about iCheck.

Comment: Otherwise it must be a way to do this with ICheck.js.. I works fine with native/default checkbox btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have only a little mistake, you should use `ifChanged` callback instead of `ifChecked`.

```
$('.myCheck').on('ifChanged', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getCategoryItems',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            name: $(this).attr("name")
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#displayCarsSection").append(data);
        }
    });

    } else {
        $("#displayCarsSection").html('');
    }
});
```

So now, this will listen in every check/uncheck

Source: http://icheck.fronteed.com/